# UICollectionView Doesn't Respond Until Scrolling Completely Stops

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cgaffinetransform

I have a standard, working `uicollectionview` and my issue is when I scroll vertically, the `uicollectionview` doesn't respond to any subsequent touch (i.e. stop scroll) until after the scroll comes to a complete halt.

I was able to pin the issue down to the `willDisplayCell` delegate method where I'm animating each displaying cell with a bubble effect. I'm curious if there is anything within this I can be advised on where I'd still be able to retain the animation while responding to touches appropriately?

When I comment out the delegate method entirely, the responsiveness to touch and scroll work perfectly.

Here is my code in the `willDisplayCell` delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let delay = 0.035
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: these link will help you,https://medium.com/@nathangitter/building-fluid-interfaces-ios-swift-9732bb934bf5https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/803/

Answer (score 1):

Played around with your code and it seems that the problem originates from the fact that you're animating the cell itself, but if you animate the cell content instead, then the collection view is responsive while scrolling and at the same time keeping the bubble animation.

For example put all cell content inside one container view inside the cell, and animate that container view instead of animating the cell itself.

```
final class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .green
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? Cell else { return }
    cell.backgroundView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let delay = 0.035
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            // you should reset the transform to CGAffineTransform.identity instead of CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1).
            cell.backgroundView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            // Not sure why you call layoutIfNeeded() here?, but without it the animation is much smoother.
            //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate this answer and it was definitely helpful leading in the right direction! The collectionView is definitely more responsive, but it's still at times, while the collectionview is scrolling, requiring multiple taps or a complete stop for interaction to continue. Not sure if there's any more exploration or info i can provide to match the responsiveness present when willDisplay is completely removed?